# Reducing number of calls to Google Analytics API with PHP

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

I've got a PHP script that uses the Google Analytics API to connect to my GA and pull the profile ID for each of my 320 clients. I'm using the account summaries list method to obtain the Profile ID for each account.

What I would like to accomplish with this script is to check all of our client sites within Google Analytics and call the Reporting API and query for the number of sessions for the last seven days. If there is no data over the last 7 days for that profile ID, it will let me know.

My issue is, I'm having to call the reporting API for each profile ID and this is taking a VERY VERY long time (about 2 minutes for the script to complete).
So this function is being called many many times:

```
 function getResults($analytics, $profileId) {
    // Calls the Core Reporting API and queries for the number of sessions
   // for the last seven days.
   return $analytics->data_ga->get(
       'ga:' . $profileId,
       '7daysAgo',
       'today',
       'ga:sessions');
  }
```

I'm wondering if there is a way I can accomplish this without my script taking so long to run.

Here is my working code:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 800);
// Load the Google API PHP Client Library.
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
$ProfileIDWithDomain = array();
$analytics = initializeAnalytics();
$profiles = getProfileIds($analytics);

foreach ($profiles as $key => $value){
   //$key is profile id $value is domain
   $results = getResults($analytics, $key);
   printResults($results,$key,$value);
}

function initializeAnalytics()
{
   // Creates and returns the Analytics Reporting service object.

   // Use the developers console and download your service account
   // credentials in JSON format. Place them in this directory or
   // change the key file location if necessary.
   $KEY_FILE_LOCATION = __DIR__ . '/{KEY_FILE}';

  // Create and configure a new client object.
  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setApplicationName("Hello Analytics Reporting");
  $client->setAuthConfig($KEY_FILE_LOCATION);
  $client->setScopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']);
  $analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);

  return $analytics;
}

function getResults($analytics, $profileId) {
   // Calls the Core Reporting API and queries for the number of sessions
   // for the last seven days.
   return $analytics->data_ga->get(
       'ga:' . $profileId,
       '7daysAgo',
       'today',
       'ga:sessions');
 }

 function printResults($results, $profile,$domain) {
    // Parses the response from the Core Reporting API and prints
    // the profile name and total sessions.
    if (count($results->getRows()) < 1) {
        echo "<div class='item'>";
        print "No results found for $profile, domain name: $domain";
        echo "</div>";
    }
  }

  function getProfileIds($analytics){

      try {
          $accounts = $analytics->management_accountSummaries
      ->listManagementAccountSummaries();
      } catch (apiServiceException $e) {
          print 'There was an Analytics API service error '
          . $e->getCode() . ':' . $e->getMessage();

      } catch (apiException $e) {
          print 'There was a general API error '
          . $e->getCode() . ':' . $e->getMessage();
      }

      foreach ($accounts->getItems() as $account) {

          foreach ($account->getWebProperties() as $property) {
              // Iterate through each Property.
              foreach ($property->getProfiles() as $profile) {
                 // Iterate through each view (profile).              
                 $ProfileIDWithDomain[$profile->getId()] = $property->getWebsiteUrl();
              }
           }
        }

       return $ProfileIDWithDomain;
    }
```